# Intention of "Grammar-style" tag and how to proceed with it

Tags: discussion

The tag [grammar-style](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-style) is currently used for just 7 question (when looking today) and has no tag description at all, neither short nor extended.

From the referring questions I assume this is used as a kind of shorthand for

> Is grammar mandating this or is it a matter of style?

I tend to drop the tag without replacement and find more targeted tags for the few questions having it as the only one.

Any comments or historical knowledge?